# display input in divs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to populate divs based on input. It works fine (I tried it.) at http://jsfiddle.net/2ufnK/2/ but when I implemented it at http://communitychessclub.com/cccr-pairing/test.html it didn't work. I wonder why...

```
<div class = "ui-widget white"><input id = "W01" name = "w01" type = "text" onchange="screen_W01()" class = "automplete-2" autofocus></div>
<div class = "ui-widget black"><input id = "B01" name = "b01" type = "text" onchange="screen_B01()" class = "automplete-2" ></div><br />
<div class = "ui-widget white"><input id = "W02" name = "w02" type = "text" onchange="screen_W02()" class = "automplete-2"></div>
<div class = "ui-widget black"><input id = "B02" name = "b02" type = "text" onchange="screen_B02()" class = "automplete-2"></div><br />
```

and:

```
<script>
function screen_W01(){var x = document.getElementById("W01"); var div = document.getElementById('WD01'); div.innerHTML = x.value;}
function screen_B01(){var x = document.getElementById("B01"); var div = document.getElementById('BD01'); div.innerHTML = x.value;}

function screen_W02(){var x = document.getElementById("W02"); var div = document.getElementById('WD02'); div.innerHTML = x.value;}
function screen_B02(){var x = document.getElementById("B02"); var div = document.getElementById('BD02'); div.innerHTML = x.value;}
</script>
```

the HTML to display the values...

```
<div id="WD01"></div>
<div id="BD01"></div>
<div id="WD02"></div>
<div id="BD02"></div>
```

But it just doesn't work: the values aren't displayed. Can someone suggest a better way (jquery preferred) or correct my coding error?

Comment: A few things to check: 1) Are any of the functions actually called? 2) Are x and div defined after you get them? 3) Is x.value defined?

Comment: mmm... What actually is in your implementation is `<input type="text" class="automplete-2 ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">`... No `id`... And no traces of the script you posted in question. Forgot to update your site???

Comment: Had some trouble updating the site with cURL and filezilla, but now everything is current and updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using ONE function for all inputs and corresponding divs.

It uses "string manipulation" on the input `id` to deduct the target's `id.`

```
$(".ui-widget input").on("change", function(){
  var inputID = $(this).attr("id");    // Ex: W01

  // Add the "D"
  var divID = inputID.substr(0,1)+"D"+inputID.substr(1);    // Ex: W + D + 01
  console.log(inputID);

  var inputValue = $(this).val();
  $(document).find("#"+divID).html(inputValue);
});
```

And the markup for the inputs would be (Just remove the "onchange=...")

```
<div class = "ui-widget white">
  <input id = "W01" name = "w01" type = "text" class = "automplete-2" autofocus>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely 100% spot on!

Answer (score -1):

I might be way off on this; I'm fairly new to all of this as well. I do see you have

```
<div class = "ui-widget white"><input id = "W01" name = "w01" type = "text" onchange="screen_W01()" class = "automplete-2" autofocus></div>
```

and

```
function screen_W01(){var x = document.getElementById("W01"); var div = document.getElementById('WD01'); div.innerHTML = x.value;}
```

where your `id = "W01"` for both, but in your HTML values you have

```
<div id="WD01"></div>
```

which has `id="WD01"`. Could this be the reason it's not working? All of the HTML values have the added 'D'. That's the only thing I can see based off what's here.

Comment: var div = document.getElementById('WD01'); (is part of the script)

Comment: Yep, missed it. That was my best guess.